# Merge ext2, ext3, ext4 to extfs (and synonymize)?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Each of the ext-tags alone is not that much frequented currently. We have: [ext2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ext2) (x5), [ext3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ext3) (x2) and [ext4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ext4) (x8).

Shouldn't we merge them together into a new [extfs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extfs), and convert the 3 old ones into synonyms? Or do they really make sense stand-alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. They're certainly related, but an "ext4" solution will not apply to "ext2" and vice-versa.

It just doesn't "feel" right to me.